# GMAP.NET - Put marker in X,Y coordinates of the map by clicking in the map

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-maps, gmap.net

I have read a lot about this API. I am starting with it and finally I achieved to put markers by clicking using the MouseDown event in the map using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers;
using System.Globalization;

namespace GMapApplicationCSharp

{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    //GMarkerGoogle marker;
    GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay("markers");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void mapaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mapa.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
        mapa.CanDragMap = true;
        mapa.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
        mapa.SetPositionByKeywords("Madrid, Spain");
        mapa.MinZoom = 0;
        mapa.MaxZoom = 24;
        mapa.Zoom = 9;
        mapa.AutoScroll = true;
        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
        //mapa.Overlays.Add(markers);
    }

    private void recargaMapaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMapas.Text == "Google Maps Satélite")
            mapa.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleSatelliteMap;
        if (IsMapas.Text == "Google Maps Callejero")
            mapa.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
        if (IsMapas.Text == "Google Maps Híbrido")
            mapa.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleHybridMap;
        if (IsMapas.Text == "OpenStreetMap")
            mapa.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;
        if (IsMapas.Text == "OpenCycleMap")
            mapa.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenCycleMap;

        mapa.Refresh();
    }

    //private void mapa_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    //{
        //double lat;
        //double lng;
        //if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        //{
        //    lat = mapa.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lat;
        //    lng = mapa.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lng;
        //    GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay("markers");
        //    GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(lat, lng), GMarkerGoogleType.blue_pushpin);
        //    markers.Markers.Add(marker);
        //    mapa.Overlays.Add(markers);
        //    Console.WriteLine("LAT: ");
        //    Console.WriteLine(lat);
        //    Console.WriteLine("LON: ");
        //    Console.WriteLine(lng);

        //}
    //}

    //private void SetMarcadorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{

    //}

    private void mapa_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //double lat;
        //double lng;

        //lat = Convert.ToDouble(LatitudTextBox.Text);
        //lng = Convert.ToDouble(LongitudTextBox.Text);
        //GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay("markers");
        //GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(lat, lng), GMarkerGoogleType.blue_pushpin);
        //markers.Markers.Add(marker);
        //mapa.Overlays.Add(markers);

        //base.OnMouseMove(e);
        //Application.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        double X = mapa.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lng;
        double Y = mapa.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lat;

        //string longitude = X.ToString();
        //string latitude = Y.ToString();
        //LatitudTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(double.Parse(latitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        //LongitudTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(double.Parse(longitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));


        GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(Y, X), GMarkerGoogleType.blue_pushpin);
        markers.Markers.Add(marker);
        mapa.Overlays.Add(markers);
    }
}
}
```

Sorry for all commented lines..

My problem is that in the first click in the map, it always put the first marker in the center of the map. I don't know why, but it only happens in the first click, because in the following clicks, I can see the markers in the coordinates I am clicking.

Maybe there is something I am not seeing? Why the first click always put the marker in the center?

Also, if someone knows, there is some way to store the maps in cache if I want to use the application offline? Maybe with some function or something like that. Because I have been taking a look in the "ServerOnly", "ServerAndCache" and "CacheOnly" functions, but I don't know how to use them properly. Imagine that I want to use my application somewhere where I haven't Internet.

**EDIT:**
Here I leave the code in VB.NET (more cleane that the other one). I have converted the code because VB is the language where I program usually, and, of course, I have the same problem:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports GMap.NET.MapProviders
Imports GMap.NET
Imports GMap.NET.WindowsForms
Imports GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Form1

Dim markers As GMapOverlay = New GMapOverlay("markers")

Private Sub CargarButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CargarButton.Click
    mapa.DragButton = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left
    mapa.CanDragMap = True
    mapa.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap
    mapa.SetPositionByKeywords("Madrid, Spain")
    mapa.MinZoom = 0
    mapa.MaxZoom = 24
    mapa.Zoom = 9
    mapa.AutoScroll = True
    GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache
End Sub

Private Sub mapa_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles mapa.MouseDown
    Dim X As Double = mapa.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lng
    Dim Y As Double = mapa.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y).Lat

    Dim marker As GMarkerGoogle = New GMarkerGoogle(New PointLatLng(Y, X), GMarkerGoogleType.green)
    markers.Markers.Add(marker)
    mapa.Overlays.Add(markers)
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the overlay once to the map. Only then add markers to the overlay. It's the wrong order, as the overlay is not attached to the map instance one you add the first marker to the overlay, hence the wrong position.

Think you should exclude the caching part and create a separate question.

Comment: Just what you suggest!! First the overlay, after the marker. What I don't understand is why in every examples on Internet, everybody puts the marker first. Thanks a lot!